# Sorting points by angle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, point

I have a group of points which I'd like to wrap with a border. But for that I need to have all my points to be sorted in a clock-wise order.

[image]

So using the below methods I'm :

- calculating center point
- for each point then compute an angle relative to the center point.
- sort the array of points by angle.

.

```
findCenter: function( points ){
        var x = 0, y = 0, i, len = points.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            x += points[i].x;
            y += points[i].y;
        }
        return { x: x / len, y: y / len };
    },

    findAngles: function(c, points){
        var i, len = points.length, p, dx, dy;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            p = points[i];
            dx = p.x - c.x;
            dy = p.y - c.y;
            p.angle = Math.atan2( dy, dx );
        }
    },

    sortByAngle: function( points ){
        points.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.angle > b.angle) return 1;
          else if (a.angle < b.angle) return -1;
          return 0;
        });
    },

    sortPoints: function( points ){
        var c = this.findCenter( points );
        this.drawPoint( c , "blue" )
        this.findAngles( c, points );
        this.sortByAngle( points );
        return points;
    },
```

But for some reason I'm getting some points switched ( see points 17, 18 )... Not sure if I should add a distance from center into consideration while sorting the array. Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

It's worth mentioning that even though I'm able to draw the border around this area, I'm getting incorrect results while testing whether a point lies inside this area or not.

Comment: This is not a coding problem. Your code works perfect. If you draw a line between 17 18 and the center you will see that 17 has a smaller angle. So i would.recommend you to "walk" along the path

Comment: As you have noticed, your algorithm won't produce the bound your searching for, if you want the edges to connect in a hexagonal fashion. Model your actual approach ("walking" as Jonas called it): find the hexagons on the boundary, start at any one of them, connect the edges in ccw order, once you reach a vertex connected to the next boundary hexagon, switch over, repeat until you find the starting hexagon.

Comment: Yes, I can draw the border correctly,but it's then messing my results when trying to test whether any point is inside this area. So I need to fix this ordering issue.

Comment: What about choosing a point (a) search for the nearest points (there are two) choose the one that isnt already checked, goto (a)

Comment: @Jonas that's actually a good insight and pretty straight forward: I was overthinking it in trying to border some points lying in the hexagonal grid.

Comment: Your original approach can work with Convex polygon only. Rule will work on 1 and 2 hexagons. 3 hexagons in line - first time clockwise approach show undefined behavior. 4 hexagons in one line and clockwise rule is broken. 
The worst case - you have only point coordinates. You can do nothing but calculate distance matrix. Each point has two nearest neighbours and you can see them in distance matrix.
The realistic case - in fact you have information about neighbourhood of each point. Combine it with boundary points list and you will get boundary chain.